# Eclipse/sunlight detection for LEO satellites

Tags: orbital-mechanics, python, poliastro

I am trying to use poliastro to obtain the positions of the propagated spacecraft and the lighting conditions at each position.
The documentation [in poliastro page](https://docs.poliastro.space/en/stable/examples/Detecting%20Events.html) shows an example of the shadow function and the event detectors, but some aspects are undocumented and hard to understand.

From the above link

```
umbra_event = UmbraEvent(orbit, terminal=True)
events = [umbra_event]

tofs = np.arange(0, 600, 30) << u.s
method = CowellPropagator(events=events)
rr, vv = orbit.to_ephem(EpochsArray(orbit.epoch + tofs, method=method)).rv()
print(
    f"The umbral shadow entry time was {umbra_event.last_t} after the orbit's epoch"
)

The umbral shadow entry time was 524.7274279607626 s after the orbit's epoch

Note: Even though the eclipse events UmbraEvent and PenumbraEvent take the Orbit as input, they are not used in propagation but used only to access some helpful attributes of the orbit.
```

From [UmbraEvent page](https://docs.poliastro.space/en/stable/autoapi/poliastro/twobody/events/index.html?highlight=umbraevent#poliastro.twobody.events.UmbraEvent)

```
 class poliastro.twobody.events.UmbraEvent(orbit, terminal=False, direction=0)¶

    Bases: EclipseEvent

    Detect whether a satellite is in umbra or not.

    Parameters

            orbit (poliastro.twobody.orbit.Orbit) – Orbit of the satellite.

            terminal (bool, optional) – Whether to terminate integration when the event occurs, defaults to False.

            direction (float, optional) – Handle triggering of event based on whether entry is into or out of umbra, defaults to 0, i.e., event is triggered at both, entry and exit points.
```

1. The detector identifies both entry and exit events by default (direction =0 ). How can I differentiate between an entry and exit event in that context?
2. The documentation does not specify the value needed for direction to detect only entry or exit events. Through experimentation I figured it accepts -1 and +1, but which is entry and exit is still unknown.
3. The shadow function demonstrated is not explained in regards to the units shown and the output value range. I get both negative and positive values, in the range -9e6 ... 2e6 , but I can find no indication of how I can translate this to a binary light/no light condition.

Comment: As an alternative, the source code for Vallado's book also has a "shadow" implementation.  The link below has the source in a few languages, and if you search around, you should be able to find unofficial source in most popular languages. https://celestrak.org/software/vallado-sw.php